# Can't apply background image to div

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project9.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-512.png">
</head>
<body>

<div class="back">


</div>

</body>
</html>




*{

   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.back{

    
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Back ground Image does not show up in (.back) div but it does work on body tag.
I've checked the name of the file and everything but it shows up blank.

Comment: specify width and height of the div

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the div a `width` and a `height`:

```css
.back{
    background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```